# Why is my PHP array not posting as an array to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, jquery-ui

This is my first time building my own JavaScript code so not completely up to speed with it yet.

I am querying my MySQL database to get all the disabled days so that the results are disabled in the date picker. I nearly have this working but the problem is that only one set of values is being posted to the JavaScript variable when there are two being read from the database. i.e if there are two bookings in my database, one from 6/3/15 - 10/3/15 and one from 14/3/15 - 17/3/15 only one is being stored in the JavaScript variable. i.e 6/3/15 - 10/3/15.

When I echo the json_encode($date_list) i get the results as:

```
["2015-3-14","2015-3-15","2015-3-16","2015-3-17","2015-3-17"] 
["2015-3-6","2015-3-7","2015-3-8","2015-3-9","2015-3-10","2015-3-10"]
```

Which is correct but when I do a console.log on the bookedDays variable the only values stored are:

```
["2015-3-6", "2015-3-7", "2015-3-8", "2015-3-9", "2015-3-10", "2015-3-10"]
```

Below is the code I am using.

```
<?php
    $bookeddates = "SELECT fromdate, todate FROM messages WHERE listing_id = '".$_GET['listingid']."'";
        $resultbookeddates = mysql_query($bookeddates) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>" . $bookeddates);
        while ($rowbookeddates = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultbookeddates)) {


            $from = date('Y-n-j', strtotime($rowbookeddates['fromdate']));
            $to = date('Y-n-j', strtotime($rowbookeddates['todate']));

            $start_time = strtotime($from);
            $end_time = strtotime($to);
            $date_list = array($from);

            $current_time = $start_time;

            while($current_time < $end_time) {
                //Add one day
                $current_time += 86400;
                $date_list[] = date('Y-n-j',$current_time);
            }

            $date_list[] = $to;   




?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bookedDays = <?php echo json_encode($date_list); ?>;
</script>

                     <?php
                     echo json_encode($date_list); 

            } ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are overwriting the `bookedDays` variable on each iteration (in each `<script>` tag). It will only keep the last value. Try adding `console.log(bookedDays);` right before `</script>`, you'll see all of them appear, it's just overwritten later.

Comment: @blex - How would I resolve this? I have closed the } before the opening script tag but same issue :/

Comment: You should not output json in your loop, generate a data structure containing all information and output it at as json the very end.

Comment: @jeroen - Without sounding silly, how do I do that? Do you know of any examples?

Comment: You just need to move the `<script>` tag under the last `}`

Comment: Define your array `$date_list` before the loop (note that neither answer at this moment does that...), fill in in the loop like you do now and output it after the loop.

Comment: And note that you have an sql injection problem.

Comment: Thanks @jeroen - That worked, then I seen Matt's suggestion below which done the same thing. Thanks very much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to move your injected JS outside of your while loop like this.  As said in comments, build your data first, then output it.

```
<?php
    $bookeddates = "SELECT fromdate, todate FROM messages WHERE listing_id = '".$_GET['listingid']."'";
        $resultbookeddates = mysql_query($bookeddates) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>" . $bookeddates);
        $date_list = array();
        while ($rowbookeddates = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultbookeddates)) {


            $from = date('Y-n-j', strtotime($rowbookeddates['fromdate']));
            $to = date('Y-n-j', strtotime($rowbookeddates['todate']));

            $start_time = strtotime($from);
            $end_time = strtotime($to);
            $date_list[] = $from;

            $current_time = $start_time;

            while($current_time < $end_time) {
                //Add one day
                $current_time += 86400;
                $date_list[] = date('Y-n-j',$current_time);
            }

            $date_list[] = $to;   

       } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var bookedDays = <?php echo json_encode($date_list); ?>;
</script>

                     <?php
                     echo json_encode($date_list);
```

Comment: welcome. just a tip, if youre getting unexpected results, view the page source and check what its outputting. Youd have seen lots of `var bookeddays` declarations that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the asigment of javascript variable.
Please, move outside the while loop the asigment and you can see all results.

```
<?php
    $bookeddates = "SELECT fromdate, todate FROM messages WHERE listing_id = '".$_GET['listingid']."'";
    $resultbookeddates = mysql_query($bookeddates) or die(mysql_error() . "<br>" . $bookeddates);
    while ($rowbookeddates = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultbookeddates)) {


        $from = date('Y-n-j', strtotime($rowbookeddates['fromdate']));
        $to = date('Y-n-j', strtotime($rowbookeddates['todate']));

        $start_time = strtotime($from);
        $end_time = strtotime($to);
        $date_list = array($from);

        $current_time = $start_time;

        while($current_time < $end_time) {
            //Add one day
            $current_time += 86400;
            $date_list[] = date('Y-n-j',$current_time);
        }

        $date_list[] = $to;  


        } ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var bookedDays = <?php echo json_encode($date_list); ?>;
</script>
```